# Почему Promise { <pending> }?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Вот то место, где я вызываю асинхронную функцию:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  message.channel.send('pong!');
  let data = "";
  let ref = chillbotDBWork.newRef(`/${message.author.id}`);
  data = await chillbotDBWork.readData(ref).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
  console.log(data);
};
```

А вот сама эта функция:

```
exports.readData = async function(ref) {
    let data;
    await ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val()) data = snapshot.val();
    });
    return data;
};
```

При выполнении кода выводится Promise { <pending> }. Как это обрабатывать? Как из промиса получить данные?

Comment: что такое `ref` и что за метод `on` у него?

Comment: В данном случае - скорее всего никак

Comment: @Grundy, а вы не видите пометку Firebase? В данном случае я хочу прочитать данные из базы данных FIrebase.

Comment: [tag:firebase] это конечно хорошо, но угадать, где в указанном коде объекты firebase, где пользовательские объекты, а где объекты какой-либо другой библиотеки - невозможно.

Comment: @Grundy, потому что я сделал для них отдельный модуль. Увы, если я буду всё расписывать в одном js файле, когда их штук 7 таких - это слишком муторно и неудобно:)
Да и вроде с названий переменных (тот же ref) нетрудно догадаться, что я возвращаю результат функции database.ref().

Comment: @Grundy проблема заключается в том, что метод on() сразу передаёт управление функции readData() из-за чего она возвращает результат undefined. Как раз это мне и нужно исправить. И  промисы были бы отличным решением этой проблемы.

Comment: Фактически, у тебя есть событие, в котором приходят данные, и тебе их нужно получить. Есть уже такой вопрос с ответами и примерами решений.

Comment: @Grundy, этот вопрос с ответами и примерами решений мне непонятен. Я не могу подогнать решение под свой код, под свою проблему.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111301/discussion-between-grundy-and-vanyavanya).

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так

```
exports.readData = function(ref) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val()) 
            resolve(snapshot.val());
        else
            reject('No data');
    });
};



 module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  message.channel.send('pong!');
  let data = "";
  let ref = chillbotDBWork.newRef(`/${message.author.id}`);
  data = await chillbotDBWork.readData(ref);
  console.log(data);
};
```